# How much H.P. does the B.A.D. bloon have?

Tags: bloons-td-6

So I have just started playing bloon tower defense 6 and on round 100 there is this massive purple M.O.A.B. class bloon called a B.A.D. bloon and it looks like it has so much health. I need to figure out how much H.P. it has so I can plan out a good defense. Does anyone know how much H.P. the B.A.D. bloon has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Big_Airship_of_Doom_(B.A.D.)

The wiki uses a metric called Red Bloon Equivalent (RBE), meaning how many red bloon equivalents are contained within the balloon. The Big Airship of Doom (B.A.D.) has the highest non-boss RBE in the current game.

- **Normal:** 55,760 RBE (20,000 HP)
- **Fortified:** 98,360 RBE (40,000 HP)